# SKAction follow UIBezierPath function not working SpriteKit - Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

In my app I have a Sprite circling around another sprite. I want this sprite to speed up when the screen is held down. I have achieved the speed up function, but I cannot seem to figure out why the sprite resets back to a certain position when the screen is clicked and after it is let go. I have a feeling I know why, but I have tried to fix it and I cannot seem to get any closer to a solution. Code below.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let dx = Slider.accessibilityActivationPoint.x
    let dy = Slider.accessibilityActivationPoint.y

    let rad = atan2(dx, dy)

    let Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 90, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 400)
    //let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(75, duration: 100)

    Slider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


    let dx = Slider.accessibilityActivationPoint.x
    let dy = Slider.accessibilityActivationPoint.y

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

    let Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 90, startAngle: 9, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 150)


    Slider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())
}

func moveClockWise(){

    let dx = Slider.position.x / 2
    let dy = Slider.position.y / 2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)


    let Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 90, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

    let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 150)
    //let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(75, duration: 100)

    Slider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())
    //Slider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate).reversedAction())
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side Note:  you shouldnt use uppercase on variables.  Uppercase is reserved for class Names..

for example:

```
let slider = Slider()
```

it's a naming convention thats used across pretty much all programming languages :)

Anyway.. try doing

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let Slider = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10, 10))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        Slider.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
        addChild(Slider)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


        let dx = Slider.accessibilityActivationPoint.x
        let dy = Slider.accessibilityActivationPoint.y

        let rad = atan2(dx, dy)

        let Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 90, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

        let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 400)
        //let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(75, duration: 100)

        if !Slider.hasActions() {
            Slider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())
        } else {
            Slider.runAction(SKAction.speedTo(1, duration: 0))
        }



    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        Slider.runAction(SKAction.speedTo(0.4, duration: 0))

    }

    func moveClockWise(){

        let dx = Slider.position.x / 2
        let dy = Slider.position.y / 2

        let rad = atan2(dy, dx)


        let Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 90, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)

        let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 150)
        //let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(75, duration: 100)

        Slider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())
        //Slider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate).reversedAction())

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this right before each one and it does not work. Any other ideas?